# C# Soap Web Service WSDL

Tags: c#

I have generated stubs from a wsdl file in a asp.net web app.  My question is how do i add those function calls to a httpwebrequest?  I have gotten this far but dont know how to finish it off and send the soap off on the wire.

```
public HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string webMethod)
{
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("");
        webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", "\"http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0/"+ webMethod +"\"");
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MR_ServerSoapClient soapClient = new MR_ServerSoapClient(endPoint,uri);
        PingURLRequest request = new PingURLRequest();
        PingURLResponse response = new PingURLResponse();

    }
```

Comment: Is MR_ServerSoapClient a class generated by the C# web service generator?

Comment: Yes it is generated by the serviceutil

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would not use the client methods generated for you, but:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
   var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
   var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: well that's kind of my question, do i still use the httpwebrequest or just the methods provided by the methods generated such as above.

Comment: providing you are not trying to do anything too fancy, you shouldn't need to use the request/response methods directly. You just call the methods of the generated `MR_ServerSoapClient` class

Comment: thanks paul, could you provide a sample code? I'm really a newbie at soap.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't provide sample code, as I don't have the wsdl for the service you are trying to call. But, for example, if there was a web method called `PingURL`, you might call it like so: `var response = MR_ServerSoapClient.PingURL();`

Comment: Yes it does, soapClient.PingURL() so i just pass that to the response variable?  do i not use the PingURLRequest() then?  Here is a demo site that has the wsdl i am using. http://demo.turtletech.com/latest/webAPI/MR_CB.asmx?op=PingURL

Comment: no, you don't need to create a `PingURLRequest` object. You generally create `xxxRequest` objects for methods that require parameters